# Python running calculations on many user inputs

Tags: python, exception, input, while-loop

I want my program to take any number of scores from any number of students, and run calculations on them.

```
student_number = 1

    try:
        score = int(input("Please enter Student " + str(student_number) + "'s score (-1: Exit): "))
    except:
        print("The score entered is not a number. Please enter it again.")
        score = int(input("Please enter Student " + str(student_number) + "'s score (-1: Exit): "))
    while score != -1:
        try:
            score = int(input("Please enter Student " + str(student_number) + "'s score (-1: Exit): "))
        except:
            print("The score entered is not a number. Please enter it again.")
            score = int(input("Please enter Student " + str(student_number) + "'s score (-1: Exit): "))
    more_student = input("Any more student? (Yes or No): ")
    while more_student == "Yes":
        student_number = student_number + 1
        try:
            score = int(input("Please enter Student " + str(student_number) + "'s score (-1: Exit): "))
        except:
            print("The score entered is not a number. Please enter it again.")
            score = int(input("Please enter Student " + str(student_number) + "'s score (-1: Exit): "))
        while score != -1:
            score = int(input("Please enter Student " + str(student_number) + "'s score (-1: Exit): "))
        more_student = input("Any more student? (Yes or No): ")
    print("done")
```

Instead of print("done"), I want to somehow take every input I have received and be able to split it up by student, example output:

Student _ has 4 scores. Their average score is _.
Student _ has 3 scores. Their average score is _.

Comment: you can use list. or array.append the score until its done and then retrieve them.

Comment: @sittsering if I use list, should I generate a blank list at the very start and then add to it after every input with list.append?

Comment: Yes! Check this link "https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp" to learn more about lists

Comment: thank you both very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just finished typing this up for another question of yours that got deleted -- it looks like the same basic problem as this one.

The approach in a nutshell (as I see the accepted answer to this version of the question is already doing) is to use two nested loops, breaking them when it's time to go to the outer loop.

```
scores = []
while True:
    scores.append([])
    while True:
        try:
            score = int(input(
                f"Please enter Student {len(scores)}'s score (-1: Exit): "
            ))
            if score == -1:
                break
            scores[-1].append(score)
        except ValueError:
            print("The score entered is not a number. Please enter it again.")
    if input("Any more student? (Yes or No): ").lower() != "yes":
        break
print(scores)
```

```
Please enter Student 1's score (-1: Exit): 78
Please enter Student 1's score (-1: Exit): 34
Please enter Student 1's score (-1: Exit): -1
Any more student? (Yes or No): yes
Please enter Student 2's score (-1: Exit): 45
Please enter Student 2's score (-1: Exit): -1
Any more student? (Yes or No): No
[[78, 34], [45]]
```

Answer (score 2):

i'd use a dictionary i guess ? This will allow to collect data for each student, namely.

```
scores = {}
student = input("Student ? ")   # Ask for student

if(student not in scores.keys()): # Create new student if necessary
    scores[student] = []

score = int(input("Score ? "))  # Generate & store score for the student
scores[student].append(score)
```

Then to compute for each student the mean of the scores ... So many possibilities. The easiest one to me:

```
for student, score_list in scores.items():
    nb_scores = len(score_list)
    mean_score = sum(score_list)/len(score_list)
    print("Student {} had {} scores, with a mean of {}". format(student, nb_scores, mean_score))
```

Comment: This is great, lots of options, thank you for your help.

Comment: For more information, you can visit the dict tab from w3school (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I included two infinite loops that breaks when -1 is entered. A hashmap is used where every Student ID is a key and is initialized with an empty array that stores the marks as the second loop executes itself.

```
marks = {}
while True:
    i = int(input("Enter Student ID or press -1 to exit"))
    if i == -1:
        break
    else:
        marks[i] = []
        while True:
            x = int(input("Enter Mark or press -1 to exit"))
            if x!=-1:
                marks[i].append(x)
            else:
                break


for i in marks.keys():
    count = len(marks[i])
    avg = sum(marks[i])/count
    print("Student {} has {} scores. Their average is {}".format(i, count, avg))
```